# Access to a variable prints undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Hi i tried to access a variable as follows,

```
for(var k=0;k<resultSet.length;k++)
{
   alert(resultSet[k]);
   $.get('/api/TagsApi/ElementsTagsIntersect?ids='+resultSet[k], function (data) {
        testingarr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                    
            testingarr.push(data[i]["ID"]);
        }
        for (var w = 0; w <3; w++) {
             if (($.inArray(testingarr[w], selectedloc)) > -1) {
                    var str = "<input type='checkbox' name ='test[]' value='" + resultSet[k] + "'/>" + resultSet[k] + "</br>";
                    $('#childs').append(str);
                     alert(resultSet[k]);
                    break;
                }
        }
}, 'json');
```

where first alert displays the exact value what i am expecting but when it comes to the inner for loop, alert returns undefined and adds a check box with undefined side to it.. i think i am using the proper initializations but confused why it does so?

Comment: Not knowing your HTML or the contents of "resultSet" it is not possible to answer this question.

Comment: @Diodeus: then how was i able to answer it? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `k` changes value, so by the time the inner function gets called, `k` is already equal to `resultSet.length`. You can wrap the whole thing in another function and pass `k` as a parameter to bind it to a new variable that won't change with the original `k`:

```
for(var k=0;k<resultSet.length;k++)
{
  (function (result) {
    $.get('/api/TagsApi/ElementsTagsIntersect?ids='+result, function (data) {
      var testingarr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                    
        testingarr.push(data[i]["ID"]);
      }
      for (var w = 0; w <3; w++) {
        if (($.inArray(testingarr[w], selectedloc)) > -1) {
          var str = "<input type='checkbox' name ='test[]' value='" + result + "'/>" + result + "</br>";
          $('#childs').append(str);
          break;
        }
      }
    }, 'json');
  })(resultSet[k]);
}
```

Comment: what can be the solution to this then?

Comment: @u2425: see my edit. also fixed up indentation & added a `var` before `testingarr`